# wordpress -filter with custom taxonomy not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the bellow code for filter with a custom taxonomy in wordpress.but it is not working.

```
    function alter_query_so_15250127($query) {
            $tax_query = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'demographic',             
            'field' => 'id',                  
            'terms' => array( 522 ),    
            'operator' => 'IN'                    
       );
     $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
    }
    add_action('pre_get_posts','alter_query_so_15250127');
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) doc, `tax_query` is an array of arrays:

> **Important Note:** tax_query takes an array of tax query arguments arrays
>   (it takes an array of arrays)....

So, please try this:

```
function alter_query_so_15250127($query) {
        //Add wrapper here
        $tax_query = array( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'demographic',             
        'field' => 'id',                  
        'terms' => array( 522 ),    
        'operator' => 'IN'                    
   ) );
 $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','alter_query_so_15250127');
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: I thing the problem is exist only the theme switched using multy theme plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/jonradio-multiple-themes/